# iPhone Simulator Apps Crash

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

I am trying to run my app in iPhone Simulator, but it crahes on the start. Moreover, default apps (settings, Safari etc) crash too. Console doesn't show anything except

```
[Session started at 2010-07-23 13:44:07 +0400.]
Failed to launch simulated application: Unknown error.
```

and there are no crash logs in /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports. What is the problem?

XCode version 3.2.2 (version 3.2.3 crashes as well).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have seen Xcode get confused. Sometimes, a reboot fix it.

Otherwise, in the iPhone simulator, try the command "iPhone Simulator > Reset Content and Settings...".
If not, you will have to uninstall and reinstall the dev tools.

Use this command to uninstall:
`sudo <Xcode>/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all`

Comment: As I've already said, default apps don't work, so I can't reset the simulator. Rebooting does't help as well. Trying to reinstall XCode like this (previously I was just deleting the /Developer folder

Comment: Uninstalling helped! Thank you!