# MonoTouch + Facebook popup dialog never goes away

Tags: xamarin.ios

I'm using the Monotouch Facebook bindings running on the iPhone simulator as the "iPhone" device (i.e. 320x480) and when it's trying to authorize, the (in-app) popup dialog never goes away. This happens even with the sample app included with monotouch-bindings. Here's what happens:

- call Facebook.Authorize
- the **in-app** Facebook login dialog pops up
- fill in credentials and press "Log In"
- Facebook's dialog for the app comes up saying, "Already authorized"
- Tap the "Okay" button in the top right
- AppDelegate gets an OpenUrl call with a proper access token in the string
- FBSessionDelegate.DidLogin is called

... but Facebook's in-app popup dialog never goes away.

This is using the sample app included in monotouch-bindings. The facebook SDK, MonoTouch binding, and sample app were pulled from Github and built as of today. This also happens whether or not the user was already authorized for the app in Facebook.

This does **not** happen in the iPhone Simulator running at Retina resolutions. In that case, it pops out to a web view (in Safari, I think) to authorize the user, and it returns to the app properly.

Note that if I go build the HackBook sample that's included with (the native) facebook-ios-sdk and run on the simulator on the 320x480 device, it does **not** use the in-app popup. Both the native HackBook app and monotouch-bindings' FacebookSample apps use practically the same code, but this behavior difference exists.

Any ideas?

Comment: Also a follow-on question: In my own app, the Facebook SDK -always- uses the in-app popup, so my app -never- can login to Facebook. In the FacebookSample app, at least it pops out to the webview if I'm running above iPhone 3 resolution. Any ideas why the SDK would choose to only use the in-app popup?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two problems going on here.

**1.** My dev tools installation and iPhone Simulator have a problem where sometimes Safari itself won't even run. It'll do the transition-in effect and then disappear immediately. My guess is that the Facebook SDK is trying to launch Safari with a URL, and when that fails it falls back to the in-app web view.

**2.** The Facebook SDK's web view fallback could be broken (in that it never removes the web view after you've auth'd), or maybe my installation has other problems that cause the web view  to stay up.

Rebooting my Macbook and doing a Reset Content and Settings on my iOS Simulator sometimes helps Safari to launch, but usually the problem comes back eventually.

The closest stackoverflow question I could find is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3317067/iphone-simulator-apps-crash), and they recommend reinstalling Xcode. If/when I get around to doing that, I'll post whether that fixed this issue.